# fast way to get subextensions in magma?

Tags: magma

If $l \equiv  1$ mod 3 then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_l)$ has a unique cubic subextension. I've been getting this field with the following magma code

> F:=CyclotomicField(l);
>      S:=Subfields(F);
>      for i:=1 to #S do
>          if Degree(S[i][1]) eq 3 then
>              return S[i][1];
>          end if;
>      end for;

but this is very slow since it has to search through all the subfields. Does anyone know a faster way to get this cubic subextension?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, try it on appropriate Magma help forums.

Comment: This turned out to be insanely easy- sorry for the bother!

Comment: Follow-up: I later found a paper by Ennola and Turunen "On Cyclic Cubic Fields" which helped me here a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo there and you want $\ell \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. With that, this has little to do with Magma. Gauss proved that the cubic extension is generated by $g=\sum_{j=1}^{\ell-1} e^{2\pi i j^3/\ell}$. In pari-gp, if you compute $g$ with sufficient precision and do algdep(g,3) you get the cubic satisfied by $g$ and hence the field. Something similar can probably be done in magma.